# SWIG Wrapping for uint8_t and uint16_t

Tags: swig

Per the [SWIG Documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html) (21.9.1 Default primitive type mappings), the C uint8_t is mapped to a Java short which is 16 bits and the C uint_15_t is mapped to a Java int which is 32 bits.  I believe the C functions are 8 and 16 bits respectively, why does SWIG double the number of bits when wrapping in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Java types are always signed.

Thus if you have an unsigned C type that goes from 0 to 255, the smallest Java type that can represent the upper half of that range is a short.

The alternative is that you shift or somehow transform your `uint8_t` to use the negative parts of Java's `byte`, but the semantics of that are *very* counterintuitive.

Comment: that makes sense for the uint8_t but couldn't you use a short then for uint16_t then?  Why use a 32 bit int?

Comment: @c12 The exact same problem happens with the `uint16_t`. In Java a `short` ranges from -32,768 to 32,767, whilst a `uint16_t` ranges from 0 to 65,536 - where should the upper half of the `uint16_t` go if you used a `short`?

Comment: how do you get swig to use a byte instead of a short? I am using a library in java that uses bytes and passing these to from my swig interface. the upcasting of byte to short is a pain because of the signedness.

Comment: thanks Flexo. I should note that the shorts im receiving are from an array (I'm using carrays to get the getItem setItem functionality)